# Problem with C++ Partial Template Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have a situation similar to this:

```
template<class A, class B>
class MyClass<A, B>
{
  ...
  static A RARELY_USED_A;
}

// Seems to work but does not cover all possible cases, since 
// there may be instances of A that have no numeric limits.
template<class A, class B>
A MyClass<A, B>::RARELY_USED_A= std::numeric_limits<A>::max();
```

From what I saw this seems to work. However, strings may be used as A under some circumstances and so I thought I'd simply create a specialization for this special case.

```
// Does not complile
template<class B>
string MyClass<string, B>::RARELY_USED_A= "";
```

unfortunately this does not complie properly with error msg:

```
error: template definition of non-template 'std::string MyClass<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, B>::RARELY_USED_A'
```

Note that, on the othre hand, a full specialization seems to work (untested at runtime but compiles)

```
// This complies but is not gernic enough and hence useless to me
template<>
string MyClass<string, string>::RARELY_USED_A= "";
```

I assume, I must be doing something wrong. I would be really grateful if you could point out what exactly it is. I thought partical specializations were supposed to work this way.

Thanks a lot in advance.

e: edited the name of the DEFAULT_A to RARELY_USED_A, because I thought that "default" was misleading somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use inheritance to reuse and specialize without duplicating all the common code:

```
template<typename A>
struct RarelyUsedShared
{
    static A RARELY_USED_A;
};

template<typename A>
A RarelyUsedShared<A>::RARELY_USED_A = std::numeric_limits<A>::max();

template<>
string RarelyUsedShared<string>::RARELY_USED_A = "";

template<typename A, typename B>
class MyClass<A, B> : RarelyUsedShared<A>
{
  ...
};
```

Note that this will result in sharing the member across various `B`, which is ok if the member should be `const`.  If not, the helper can take two template parameters, and you can partially specialize it:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct RarelyUsedNotShared
{
    static A RARELY_USED_A;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
A RarelyUsedNotShared<A, B>::RARELY_USED_A = std::numeric_limits<A>::max();

template<typename B>
struct RarelyUsedNotShared<string, B>
{
    static A RARELY_USED_A;
};

typename<typename B>
string RarelyUsedNotShared<string, B>::RARELY_USED_A = "";

template<typename A, typename B>
class MyClass<A, B> : RarelyUsedNotShared<A, B>
{
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Sounds good. I still wonder why there is this limitation of partial specialization. But I guess this answer solves my problem in an elegant way.

Comment: Now I have another problem. Since MyClass is a container type with many possible instatiations, I cannot split it in .h and .cpp files and have to have the whole thing in the header file.

Unfortunately doing this get's my multiple definitions of RARELY_USED_A when linking a binary from multiple objects that use MyClass.

Comment: @b.buchhold: That's a new question entirely, you'd have that problem even without specialization, and needs to be asked separately.  Moreover, I think it's already been answered, so first do a search for "template static multiple definition".

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a partial specialization to your entire class, not just a single member.

Comment: hmm, that would be really annoying because it would be nothing but duplicate code for everything instead that one single member.

Also I wonder why a full specialization is possible for only this one member.

Comment: @b.buchhold: Use a helper class, that has just this one member.  Then you can specialize it without code duplication.  Your main class can inherit from it.

Comment: ... and yes, it's a bit of a pain. Note that in your working case, n.m., you're not really specialising the function at all but providing a definition for one member of _one_ specialised template instance of `MyClass`. I think.

Comment: and yes, it's a horrific, insane, ridiculous pain.

Answer (score 0):

If your `RARELY_USED` is const, you could use a little helper class:

```
template <class A, class B>
const A MyClass<A, B>::RARELY_USED_A = Helper<A>::value;

/*...*/

#include <limits>
#include <string>

template <typename A> struct Helper { static const A RARELY_USED_A; };
template <typename A> const A Helper<A>::RARELY_USED_A = std::numeric_limits<A>::max();

template <> struct Helper<std::string> { static const std::string RARELY_USED_A; };
const std::string Helper<std::string>::RARELY_USED_A = "";
```

Comment: I don't think this compiles, because neither functions calls nor initialization of strings is possible for static/const stuff, if i recall correctly.

Comment: Even in C++0x where `max()` is `constexpr`? Haven't tested it, though, so it's possible that this doesn't work.

Comment: `static` members have to be defined outside the class, even if they're initialized inside the class.